# Postgresql Deadlock - what does "while rechecking updated tuple" mean?

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

Question: Can someone please decipher `while rechecking updated tuple` for me in the following:

```
2019-02-20 10:34:26 UTC:1.2.3.4(17866):user@database:[31391]:ERROR:  deadlock detected
2019-02-20 10:34:26 UTC:1.2.3.4(17866):user@database:[31391]:DETAIL:
    Process 31391 waits for ShareLock on transaction 770573675; blocked by process 25788.
    Process 25788 waits for ShareLock on transaction 770573695; blocked by process 31391.
    Process 31391: update my_table row_to_update set col_to_update = now() from (select id from my_table where col_to_update is null order by id limit $4 for no key update) matched_row_to_update where row_to_update.id = matched_row_to_update.id returning row_to_update.id as id, row_to_update.col_to_update as col_to_update, row_to_update.other_col as other_col
    Process 25788: update my_table set col_to_update=$1 other_col=$2 where id=$3
2019-02-20 10:34:26 UTC:1.2.3.4(17866):user@database:[31391]:HINT:  See server log for query details.
2019-02-20 10:34:26 UTC:1.2.3.4(17866):user@database:[31391]:CONTEXT:  while rechecking updated tuple (36328,33) in relation "my_table"
2019-02-20 10:34:26 UTC:1.2.3.4(17866):user@database:[31391]:STATEMENT:  update my_table row_to_update set col_to_update = now() from (select id from my_table where col_to_update is null order by id limit $4 for no key update) matched_row_to_update where row_to_update.id = matched_row_to_update.id returning row_to_update.id as id, row_to_update.col_to_update as col_to_update, row_to_update.other_col as other_col
```

I found the it [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/storage/lmgr/lmgr.c#L830) but couldn't figure it out what exactly is happening there. what is the lock? and how can I debug/resolve it?

To be clear I understand what a deadlock is. I'm asking, based on the error message what is happening, or very simply what the error message means. For example, https://bit.ly/2TaWh6c or https://bit.ly/2Sk0lg0 or https://bit.ly/2E2v9g9 describe different situations with different error message. But I couldn't find anything about the error I'm getting.

**Full story:**
We have a service (multiple instances working on single DB) which does the following:

Thread #1
1. Fetch some rows from DB to process in transaction #1 (Process 31391).
2. Process fetched rows, update them.
3. Save all processed/updated rows back to DB in transaction #2 (Process 25788).

Thread #2.
1. Periodically check rows in DB which are in process mode for too long and release them by checking and setting `col_to_update` to `null` in transaction #3 (since we're using JPA/Hibernate, effectively the query is the same as Process 25788).

Previously we had deadlock errors with the message: `while updating tuple (xxx,xxx) in relation my_table` between two transactions with the same query (query of Process 31391). We managed to solve it by adding `order by id for no key update`.

Now we're getting the deadlock above which I don't understand. Even an answer to the following question would help: what's the difference between updating tuple and rechecking updated tuple?

Comment: You should just catch the error and retry the transaction, at the application/framework/abstraction layer.  Anything else could be an endless game of whack-a-mole.

Comment: If you wish to play whack-a-mole, can you tell us what previous update statements likely occurred earlier in the same transactions which are involved in this deadlock?  Also, addings process pids to log_line_prefix can be really helpful in this type of situation.

Comment: @jjanes I updated the question. Please let me know if I need to provide more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Even an answer to the following question would help: what's the difference between updating tuple and rechecking updated tuple?

I will take you up on this part.  When PostgreSQL finds a row that meets the WHERE clause to be updated, but that tuple has already been modified by a not-yet-committed transaction, it will wait for that transaction to commit and then recheck that the new version of the row still meets the WHERE clause.

So 31391 was wanting to update a tuple that 25788 had already updated (presumably in a prior statement in 25788's transaction), and was waiting for 25788 to finish so it could recheck that it still wanted to update it.

25788 was waiting or 31391 to finish, but we don't know why it was waiting for as it didn't log a CONTEXT line.

Can you tell if 25788 was implementing the 3rd step of thread #1, or is it implementing thread #2?

Does your thread #2 issue its 25788-like query each in its own transaction?

Comment: That was enlightening. It gave me some hint where to look for resolutions. Regarding the questions:
1. I don't know yet, I rewrote the query to find out.
2. Yes, it's a bunch of entities being updated and Hibernate does it in one transaction (though with one update query per entity).
Will update you about the result.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you understand what a deadlock is. If you don't, you'll find more informations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143873/how-to-explain-the-deadlock-better).

It's particularly difficult for a human brain to imagine concurrency in data writing/reading (as real time programmation is difficult for a human brain). So you should consider applying these two simple rules in your application for DML:

- Always write data in the same order in your transactions
- Keep your transactions short (the shortest you can)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I understand what a deadlock is. I'm asking based on the error message what is happening, or very simply what the error message means. For example, https://bit.ly/2TaWh6c or https://bit.ly/2Sk0lg0 or https://bit.ly/2E2v9g9 describe different situations with different error message. But I couldn't find anything about the error I'm getting.